# How can we join data of two database and that data into third table by Django query

Tags: python, join, django-models, methods, scheduler

Here I have two database table from dbtable StudentDetailModel and BooKDetailsModel I want to get the data from this  in schedular.py file by todays. when I get data from this table from todays date I want to save it in third database table named as BilledBook So Firstly I get query data from this table. I do this

```
 def get_book_date():
    today = date.today()
   
    book_details = BookByDayDetailModel.objects.filter(get_book_date=int(today.day)).values() 
    print("Student_details : ",student_details)

    for student in student_details:
        print("meter ca : ",student['ca_number_id'])
        #Get all data from student_number which gets from todays date
        student_details = get_student_details(student['student_number'])

        #Get all data from book_details which gets from todays date
        print("student book_id : ",student['book_id_id'])
        book_details = get_book_details(student['book_id_id'])

def get_student_details(ca_number):
    student_details = StudentDetailModel.objects.filter(student_number = student_number).values()
    return student_details

def get_book_details(book_id):
    book_details = BookDetailsModel.objects.filter(book_id = book_id).values()
    return book_details
```

Here I get queryset of data which get added today but Now I want to join this query set and add it into third table which named as BilledBookModel I tried this

```
 bill_book_details = BilledBookModel.objects.create(student_details,book_details)
```

But its not working Can You give some Idea how can Do this

Comment: Do you mean `tables` instead of `databases`?

Comment: yes I mean tables